# PayPal Custom Variable in Email Link

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm working on a small integrated application for one of my projects in which I can not use a form. (The project is not HTML related) and instead can only pass a link through to the browser. This link will be sued to open an "Email Button Link" to an item, the only problem is that I need to be able to pass a custom variable to this link containing some information.

Is this possible? I've been researching for about three hours, but it's just the internet being spammed with answers on how to use the custom field in the HTML form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, parameters in the email links work just the same as forms.  Just add "&custom=whatever_data_you_need" to your email link and that data will be included with the PayPal payment.