# Pass custom field in PayPal email subscription link

Tags: php, paypal

I need to pass a custom variable in a PayPal subscription email link. It has to be an email link. I have tried this [PayPal Custom Variable in Email Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731983/paypal-custom-variable-in-email-link)
but it does not seem to work, and have been unable to find another way to make it work.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

What I want to do is send, for example, Account = {account name}.

Any help greatly appreciated.

There is no code as such, just the following PayPal link:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=1234567890ABCD
```

I have tried

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=1234567890ABCD&custom={account name}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: @dgig Thanks, no code as such, just the lines I have now added. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to pass this variable? what's the end goal?

Comment: To have a record of my account reference on the actual subscription they make via PayPal so that I can identify them in my records and any further communication from PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, the answer in the other post quoted DID work, thank you for your replies.

Quote:

**Yes, parameters in the email links work just the same as forms. Just add "&custom=whatever_data_you_need" to your email link and that data will be included with the PayPal payment.**

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding an advanced variable to the button BEFORE you save it and get the code. You can add advanced variables in step 3 of the button creation process. Here is some documentation:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/#id08A1HE00C2L

Here is the variable reference:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Once the button is created with the advanced variable(s) you can still capture the email link.

Comment: I need to dynamically add the custom variable in code, for example : 

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=1234567890ABCD&custom=<?php echo $_POST['Name']; ?>

Comment: Makes sense...you might want to look at the Button Manager API documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrAPI/?mark=button%20manager